# FIrebase onDisconnect handler with timestamp not setting correct timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating on online presence using Firebase realtime database, but the onDisconnect function does not set the correct timestamp, it sets the timestamp of the time the onDisconnect function has been created/loaded.

I am using the following code:

```
func setStatusToOnline(forUser user: User) {
    let selfUserRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/\(user.uid)")
    selfUserRef.updateChildValues(["online": true])

    selfUserRef.onDisconnectUpdateChildValues(["online": false, "last_online": Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate*1000000)]) { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When the function `setStatusToOnline(user: User)` has been called at e.g. Timestamp 575825661026887 (= 575825661026887/1000000 seconds) and the user disconnects a few minutes later, it will set `575825661026887` instead of the current timestamp.

Is there a way to set the correct timestamp?

Comment: Why don't you use the firebase timestamp server value?

Comment: @AndréKool How would I do that?

Comment: I think [this is exactly what you are looking for](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps)

Comment: @AndréKool Thank you, this works!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your date was set at the time of evaluation is because you had to pass a fully created object to `onDisconnectUpdateChildValues`.  It couldn't have any delayed-execution properties to it because the names and values have to be settled at the time of the call, not at the time of the disconnect.

Comment: You could improve this answer by showing [how it could be done instead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps).